# In a Vue unit test, how do you trigger a watcher function created with the instance method $watch

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vue-test-utils

I'm writing a Vue unit test and I need to simulate a watcher getting triggered.

I initially tried triggering it by changing the value of the property that was being watched but this did not trigger the watcher.

After reading a [great article](https://vuedose.tips/testing-logic-inside-a-vue-js-watcher/) I then realised that I should be triggering the watcher and not requiring my test to check that a watcher works.

They essentially suggested that you can trigger the watcher in the following fashion:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(YourComponent);

wrapper.vm.$options.watch.someWatchedProperty.call(wrapper.vm, 'someData');
```

However, this appears not to work for watchers dynamically added using Vue's instance method `$watch`.

The logic I am trying to test is doing something like this:

```
const unwatch = this.$watch('apiErrors.length', (newValue) => {
   // some logic I want to have executed in my test
}
```

When logging `wrapper.vm.$options.watch` in my test, it is an empty object.

Is there another way to trigger this logic?

Comment: You could move the watcher's callback into `methods`, and then invoke that method through `wrapper.vm.methodName()`.

Comment: Appreciate the thought @tony19 but I prefer not to modify the real code where possible for the tests. In my specific case it didn't feel like it should live in its own function. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I decided that the best way to handle this was to mock `wrapper.vm.$watch` and provide a method that mocked the watched property. I could then trigger its execution where required.

Comment: example code would be very helpful!